# Four players from two different sports

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, sports, flags

*This list is about two former players and two active players from tennis and football.*

[image]

---

***Complete the table by filling the missing national flags and the missing player.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completed table should look like this:

> [image: Completed table]

Because...

> In each row the three flags represent:
>
>  *Top left:* Country whose standard [2-letter code](https://www.iban.com/country-codes) begins the pictured sportsperson's **first name**;
>  *Top right:* Country whose standard 2-letter code begins the pictured sportsperson's **last name**;
>  *Bottom:* The player's **nationality**.

So the top two rows are interpreted as:

> Benin (**BJ**) + Bolivia (**BO**) = **BJ**ORN **BO**RG (**Sweden**)
>
>  and
>
>  Jordan (**JO**) + Costa Rica (**CR**) = **JO**HANN **CR**UYFF (**Netherlands**)

And the bottom two need to be completed with:

> The flags of Norway (**NO**), Djibouti (**DJ**), and **Serbia** to represent the Serbian tennis player **NO**VAK **DJ**OKOVIC
>
>  and
>
>  An image of **TO**NI **KR**OOS, a current German footballer, as the flags are those of TONGA (**TO**), SOUTH KOREA (**KR**) and **Germany**.